# WiX Toolset - Alt Text to the CancelDlg's Icon

Tags: wix, wix3

I'm trying to make my app accessible (based on WCAG 2.1 guidelines).
I discovered that the default CancelDlg of WiX Toolset, which is the confirmation dialog that pops when the user tries to cancel the installation, is not accessible.

There is a yellow warning icon beside the text, but it has no Alt text or Name.
That makes narrators say "Image" instead of something along the line of "Warning icon" and confuse who is blind.

I didn't find a way to add an Alt text to that dialog that not include creating a custom dialog (which doesn't feel like the right way).

P.S. Using WiX version 3.10.

Any ideas?
Thanks!